# Proper Google DNS Config for GMail

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, g-suite, google-compute-engine

I'm having an issue configuring the MX records for my domain registered with Google Domains. Using this [tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/) but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing w wrong. Was hoping one of you pros could help me out. I've [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkmP8.png) a screenshot of my current DNS settings.

The problem is I do not get email and cannot retrieve the MX records from DNS.

Comment: You probably want to change `@.daftware.io.` to `daftware.io.`.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the problem is.

Comment: @EEAA Edited. Check above and tool link

Comment: The tool link is not helpful: it does not contain any information about your domain.

Comment: @mrjink THANK YOU! You don't even know. Crazy it was just this simple. Thanks again.

Comment: @EEAA "read" the whole post by clicking on the attached screenshot also.

Comment: @EEAA although not all the information is in the question wording, the screenshots supply enough information to be able to answer it.  Entering daftware.io in the tool showed the problem at hand.

Comment: @mrjink Originally, there was no problem statement, which is why I put the question on hold. Additionally, users should help us to help them - provide as much information here in the question as possible, and don't require folks to go chasing around for information. Anyway, it's been re-opened. Feel free to post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the guide you followed, told you to add the MX records on the domain with the `@` notation.  [The `@` refers to the `$ORIGIN` of the domain](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/index.html#generic), which is usually the registered domain name itself.  The webbased tool you used to configure the domain, interpreted that as a sub-domain `@.daftware.io`.  This is why it doesn't work.  If the tool you use doesn't allow `@`, or handles it incorrectly, you can usually just assume it's meant to be the domain name itself.  In your case, you can leave the DNS name field empty, and just enter the MX records; they will then become part of the domain.  The same applies to the `TXT` and `SPF` records that you have.

Comment: This 100% solved my problem. Thank you for the whole and complete answer. Let me know if I can buy you a beer or some equivalent.